# Django query for total balance from different currency wallets

Tags: django, django-models, aggregate-functions

What is the best way to get total balance of the user wallets with different currencies?

**myapp/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

USD = 'USD'
EUR = 'EUR'
GBP = 'GBP'
CURRENCY_CHOICES = (
    (USD, 'US Dollars'),
    (EUR, 'Euro'),
    (GBP, 'UK Pounds'),
)

class Wallet(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    accnumber = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    currency = models.CharField(choices=CURRENCY_CHOICES, default=EUR)
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9,decimal_places=2)
```

Currency rates are obtained from the [fixer.io](http://fixer.io) in a dict form
`[(u'usd', 'US Dollars'), (u'eur', 'Euro'), (u'rub', 'Russian Rubles'), (u'gbp', 'UK Pound Sterling'), (u'btc', 'Bitcoin'), (u'eth', 'Etherium')]`

**myapp/views.py**

```
import requests
from decimal import Decimal
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.db.models import Sum
from myyapp.model import Wallet, CURRENCY_CHOICES 

class TotalBalanceView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'balance.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TotalBalanceView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        #get current exchage rates from Fixer.IO
        symbols = ','.join(dict(CURRENCY_CHOICES).keys()).upper()
        uri = "http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key={}&base=EUR&symbols={}".format(FIXER_API, symbols)
        r = requests.get(uri)
        rates = r.json()['rates']

        #get account for the user
        wallets = Wallet.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        total = Decimal()
        for curr in CURRENCY_CHOICES:
            total += wallets.filter(currency=curr).aggregate(
                    total=Sum('balance'))

        context.update({
            'wallets ': wallets
            'total': total_eur + total_usd * rates['USD'] + total_gbp * rates['GBP']
        })

        return context
```

**myapp/templates/balance.html**

```
<h1>Total is: {{ total|floatformat:2 }}</h1>
{% for w in wallets %}
    <p>{{ w.accnumber }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

I am sure there should be more efficient solution using Aggregate functions in one query request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this by basically performing some sort of group by per currency:

```
totals = (wallets.values('currency')
                 .annotate(total=Sum('balance'))
                 .order_by('currency'))
```

This will result in an *iterable* of **dictionaries** where `currency` maps on the currency, and `total` that maps to the total of that currency. For example something like:

```
[{'currency': 'EUR', 'total': 123.45},
 {'currency': 'USD', 'total': 456.78},
 {'currency': 'BFR', 'total': 901.23}]
```

We can then calculate the totals all for one currency as:

```
total = sum([subsum[total] * rate[subsum['currency']]
             for subsum in totals])
```

You will probably have to add a rate for the currency you convert to (with a rate equal to `1.00`).

Comment: @EgorBolotevich: yes, you need to swap the statements, edited.

Comment: @EgorBolotevich: did you remove the `values` at the top, so only `wallets.order_by(..)...`.

Comment: @EgorBolotevich: please edit your question with the code you used.

Comment: @EgorBolotevich: ok, I think I finally found the error with the query. See edit.